# Flutter camera do not work in the phone orientation

Tags: android, flutter, camera, orientation

everyone. I have one question about the flutter camera preview.
https://pub.dev/packages/camera
I am using this flutter camera plugin. Of course, it works as well. But it is crashed when phone orientation. Please help me if experience this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rotation causes the change in lifecycle in Android.they have mentioned this in their doc.Can you please check?

[Camera app package in pub dev](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)

Handling Lifecycle states
As of version 0.5.0 of the camera plugin, lifecycle changes are no longer handled by the plugin. This means developers are now responsible to control camera resources when the lifecycle state is updated. Failure to do so might lead to unexpected behavior (for example as described in issue #39109). Handling lifecycle changes can be done by overriding the didChangeAppLifecycleState method like so

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      controller?.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (controller != null) {
        onNewCameraSelected(controller.description);
      }
    }
  }
```